# VScode terminal shortcuts

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio Code (Windows 10), how do I create shortcuts for certain commands in the terminal?

For example, if I have

```
javac -d ./bin *.java && java -cp ./bin test
```

I would like to just automatically execute that just by typing `jrun`(made up command) in the built-in terminal.

Comment: As far as I know you can use your shell's aliases in vscode. (at least PowerShell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a Windows batch script `jrun.bat` which contains `javac -d ./bin *.java && java -cp ./bin test`, so now I can just type `jrun`. I know there's a VsCode java extension, but I'm trying to do everything manually.